# could not resolve org.apache.zookeeper in curator-framework 2.9.1

Tags: gradle, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using gradle build and added curator-framework 2.9.1 in external dependencies. When I build my code, it prompts error for missing org.apache.zookeeper.

When I opened MANIFEST.MF file for Gradle: org.apache.curator:curator-framework-2.9.1 in external libraries section of Intellij IDE, it prompts error for "could not resolve org.apache.zookeeper".

This only happens on my machine, for my colleagues it builds fine. This is for open source project dcos-cassandra-mesos.

Comment: It fails to build in both the IDE and via Gradle?

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file or at least the dependencies section?

Comment: At this branch, please see build.gradle.
https://github.com/verma7/dcos-cassandra-service/tree/statsd-metrics

Comment: You have curator as a `testCompile` dependency: `testCompile 'org.apache.curator:curator-test:2.9.1'` is that intentional?

Comment: I am not sure, it is there in original branch as well, from which this branch is forked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120453/discussion-between-varun-gupta-and-cjstehno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, rather than pointing to gradle cache binaries, it was default pointing to .m2 repository on my local machine. Due to which it was not able to find zookeeper jar files.